# How to use Android Service flags?

Tags: android

I don't understand why:

```
if((flags & (Service.START_FLAG_REDELIVERY |Service.START_FLAG_RETRY) != 0)
    // 2 flags are present.
```

because:

```
if((flags & (Service.START_FLAG_REDELIVERY |Service.START_FLAG_RETRY) != 0)
    //it means that at least one of the 2 is present.
```

suppose that flags=XY:

```
if((flags & (Service.START_FLAG_REDELIVERY |Service.START_FLAG_RETRY) != 0)
    //means that X!=0 or Y!=0 not X!=0 and Y!=0.
```

Answer (score -1):

It's binary flags and you need binary operator (|) to concat it, **not** logic operators.

Answer (score -1):

public static final int START_FLAG_REDELIVERY = 1;
public static final int START_FLAG_RETRY = 2;

0x01 | 0x02 ==> 0x03 ==>Binary 00000011 ===> & flag